# how to do in hibernate like order by to_date(ADD_DATE_CREATED,'DD-MM-YY') desc

Tags: oracle, hibernate

i want to add criteria in hibernate for order by date.

Here date description in db as

```
vrhCreatedDate varchar2(20)
```

Here i have date with varchar datatype in database .

i m doing order by using

```
order by to_date(ADD_DATE_CREATED,'DD-MM-YY') desc
```

how to add criteria like below for order by date itself ?

```
criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("to_date({alias}.vrhCreatedDate, 'DD-MM-YY')")); //need to parse varchar column in date when pass order by column in hibernate.
```

Parse order by column with string to date field.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following statment to order by your date field

```
    criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("your Field name"));
```